# How to pass / in the URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server

I am using API Manager 2.0 to expose underlying DSS resources.

How can I pass `/` as part of the path parameter value.

Example: I need to access a `REST` resource person with `date of birth` as `26/01/2017` like this `<endpoint>/person/26/01/2017`

I have tried using `%2F` as well instead of `/` like `<endpoint>/person/26%2F01%F2017`. In this case it takes whole '26%2F01%F2017' as a string and passes on to next level which will not match with any date and returns no records.

This is with API Manager only. DSS is allowing me to access with `/` without any encoding.

Thanks

Comment: Bit of investigation points that this could be an issue in DSS. Because if we  pass `%20` instead of space to DSS it works. But if we pass `%2F` instead `/` I get Bad request 400. DSS wants `/` as it is where as it treats both `%20` and space as same. If we can make DSS to accept `%2F` as part of path parameter value my problem will be resolved.

Comment: Based on the above findings the HTML URL encoding is not fully supported by DSS. It supports %20 for space but not %2F for /. Looks like a bug in DSS. Anyone aware of any open Jira for this issue?